# pdfescape not found yet it's installed with the oberdiek package

Tags: compilation-error

I'm using MikTeK to compile a document I made about year ago. It compiled fine at the time, but does not now. The error I get is that `pdfescape.sty` can't be found, yet it seems to be part of the `oberdiek` package, which I have installed. Is there another way to get this style file or a way around this error?

Comment: `pdfescape` has been split off from `oberdiek` into a stand-alone package. Try running *Tasks > Update package database* in the MikTeX Console and then install `pdfescape` via *Packages*. Alternatively, if you keep your system up to date and use on-the-fly installation of missing, just update in both Admin and User mode and then run *Tasks > Update package database* in both Admin and User mode. Then compile your document.

Comment: @moewe This did in fact solve the problem.