# Problem with letltxmacro and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, compilation-error

I am facing an issue in in TeXstudio. This file worked fine for me in the past, but suddently I am facing this issue. Initially I had a problem with `pdfescape.sty`, but it was rectified by solution provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520882/pdfescape-not-found-yet-its-installed-with-the-oberdiek-package). But now I face a problem with `letltxmacro.sty`.

My code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\begin{document}
     {\centering{\huge{Title}}\\}
     \section*{Background}
     This is a first paragraph with random words.
\end{document}
```

When I am compiling this, it is running smoothly and output is generated.

Problem starts when I uncomment and use `\usepackage{hyperref}`. While doing so, I get this comment box:

[image: CommentBox]

When I check the folder “C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek”, I could see that letltxmacro.sty is not there. So, I click “Install”. I expected it to install in the above-mentioned folder. But it was not doing it and also, I get this message:

> Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode
>   "ToStack".tex
>
> Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully
>   contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
>   C:\Users\SREERAJ\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
>
> Process exited with error(s)

Pdflatex.log looks like this:

> 2019-12-20 11:29:43,724+0530 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command
>   line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode ToStack.tex
>
> 2019-12-20 11:29:43,727+0530 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell
>   commands
>
> 2019-12-20 11:29:43,727+0530 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output)
>   from (to) processes
>
> 2019-12-20 11:30:04,081+0530 INFO  pdflatex - installing package
>   oberdiek triggered by tex/latex/oberdiek\letltxmacro.sty
>
> 2019-12-20 11:30:09,189+0530 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: starting package
>   maintenance...
>
> 2019-12-20 11:30:09,190+0530 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: installation
>   directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
>
> 2019-12-20 11:30:09,190+0530 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository:
>   http://mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
>
> 2019-12-20 11:30:09,495+0530 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository
>   digest: 70b12b46c46c22825b175610c484eca2
>
> 2019-12-20 11:30:11,407+0530 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to download
>   13961852 bytes
>
> 2019-12-20 11:30:11,408+0530 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to install
>   142 file(s) (1 package(s))
>
> 2019-12-20 11:30:12,815+0530 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: downloading
>   http://mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/oberdiek.tar.lzma...
>
> 2019-12-20 11:31:19,475+0530 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: 13.96 MB, 1.68
>   Mbit/s
>
> 2019-12-20 11:31:19,817+0530 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: extracting files
>   from oberdiek.tar.lzma...
>
> 2019-12-20 11:31:27,874+0530 FATAL pdflatex - The installed file does
>   not exist.
>
> 2019-12-20 11:31:27,874+0530 FATAL pdflatex - Info:
>   fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
>   2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\letltxmacro.sty"
>
> 2019-12-20 11:31:27,874+0530 FATAL pdflatex - Source:
>   Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\findfile.cpp
>
> 2019-12-20 11:31:27,874+0530 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 59
>
> 2019-12-20 11:31:27,874+0530 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code
>   1

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Update the package database (menu task in the miktex console. Do it in user and admin mode.)

Comment: Update your system in Admin *and* User mode (by running the MikTeX Console and then going to the Update tab). Then run *Tasks > Update package database* again in Admin *and* User mode. Then try to re-run the document and accept any on-the-fly package installation requests that might pop up. (The problem here is that `letltxmacro` and other files were split from `oberdiek` into separate packages. It seems that your `oberdiek` is new enough that it already doesn't contain these files any more, but that your package database, that MikTeX needs to find out which package to download is too old.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , it worked.

Comment: @moewe thanks for the explanation. I was updating only in the administrator mode. When I did it in both user and admin mode, the problem got resolved.
Is it necessary to update both in user and admin mode? I thought admin mode was sufficient.
Anyway, thank you. You could have written in answer form...

Comment: If you have installed a multi-user MikTeX (i.e. you have an Admin and a User mode), then it is usually required to update the installation with both Admin and User mode. Admin mode can not update User-installed packages (and vice versa).